# While loop won't close on command

Tags: python

I am a beginner with python
I have this particular function in a python script for hangman. Each time you get a correct letter, user_choices is appended, and the while loop should close and move to the next function I have once user_choices is equal to the guessing_word which is the unknown word in the puzzle. This is the last thing I need to complete the script but I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. Instead of ending the game and moving on it just continues to ask the player for more letters.
Any help is vastly appreciated.

```
def pick_letter(guessing_word):
    user_choices=[]
    incorrect_guesses=[]
    print("\nlet's play Hangman!")
    print(guessing_word)  
    print(draw_hangman(incorrect_guesses,guessing_word))
    print(revealed(user_choices,guessing_word))
    while user_choices!=guessing_word:
        if user_choices==guessing_word:
            print("Congratulations, you won!")
            break
        letter_choice=input("Please select a letter: ")
        if draw_hangman(incorrect_guesses,guessing_word)==Hangman[7]:
            print("you have lost")
            break
        if letter_choice in user_choices:
            print("You have already choosen that letter, please select a new letter.")
        elif letter_choice in guessing_word:
            user_choices.append(letter_choice)
            print(draw_hangman(incorrect_guesses,guessing_word))
            print(revealed(user_choices,guessing_word))
            print("That choice was correct! select again.")
        elif letter_choice not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print("That character is invalid, please enter one real letter, lower-case.")
        else:
            incorrect_guesses.append(letter_choice)
            print(draw_hangman(incorrect_guesses,guessing_word))
            print(revealed(user_choices,guessing_word))
            print("That letter is incorrect, please select again.")
```

Comment: In a `while` loop with the condition `user_choices!=guessing_word`, it is *utterly pointless* for the first statement to be `if user_choices==guessing_word:` - that condition is guaranteed not to be true, the loop would have already exited if it was.  But it's impossible for it to be true, anyway, because you're comparing two different types of data (list vs. string, apparently).  And even if you converted one to match the other, they'd still not be equal because they don't have the letters in the same order.

Comment: In your own words, what is `guessing_word`? What *type* is it? Why should it ever be equal to `user_choices`?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that `gussing_word` and `user_choices` are lists, you cannot compare them directly. You could try comparing them like this:

```
usr_choice_str = ''.join(user_choices)
guess_word_str = ''.join(guessing word)
if usr_choice_str.lower() == guess_word_str.lower():
    print("Congratulations, you won!")
    break
```

Here, the lists are first joined so if `guessing_word` is `['H', 'E', 'L', 'L'. 'O']`, `guess_word_str` is `'HELLO'`. Now strings can be directly compared and the problem should be solved
Edit: Converted all letters to lowercase as suggested by @KevinChoonLiangYew

Comment: `guessing_word` is a string so I will just convert the `user_choices`, thank you very much.

Comment: You need to make sure all letters are uppercase or lowercase too.